# Getting Ubuntu to Recognize USB Wifi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, drivers

So, I'm really new to Linux systems and have just downloaded Ubuntu on my other desktop.  The problem I'm having is getting it to recognize the USB wifi, TP-Link AC600 Archer T2UH.  I went to the companies website and they have a download for driver and pdf instructions.

[image]

I'm able to follow the first step, the second step, I have no idea what it means so I just skipped it.  And then the third step gives me a lot of errors.

Here's my command line output: [http://imgur.com/bUWOkFD](https://imgur.com/bUWOkFD)

Comment: Here's my command line output: http://imgur.com/bUWOkFD

Answer (score 0):

(This answer doesn't contain a working solution, but see the end of the post for details we found out while investigating.)

The instruction mentions "Linux 2.6", which is **ages** old—the current version is 4.5.2. I wouldn't expect this driver to work.

The second point is: drivers that aren't part of Linux are usually of inferior quality and lack support. So again, don't expect much.

The error you're seeing is actually quite benign: "`__DATE__` macro" is just a marker in the code that gets substituted with compilation date. It breaks reproducibility, i.e. two separate compilations of the same source won't necessary result in the same binary (because compilation dates might differ.) This *is* a problem if you care about security, but at the moment, you have bigger things to tackle as driver doesn't compile at all.

---

Note: gcc-4.9 enabled date-time warning by default, so any software that uses `-Werror` flag and contains `__DATE__` and/or `__TIME__` macro(s) now fails to build.

Things we tried that didn't work:

- setting `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` to `-Wno-error=date-time`: commands like `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=date-time" sudo -E make` didn't affect the error at all;
- running `find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/-Werror//g'` to remove the offending flag from all Makefiles didn't affect the error either (yes, we ran `make clean` before rebuilding).

Comment: Should I type the following: CXXFLAGS="-Wno-error=date-time" sudo make         and then try going through the steps again?

Comment: No, this is a variation of step three. So you go into the driver's directory and you run this command; that's it.

Comment: Didn't seem to like that either.  http://imgur.com/xzjECAB

Comment: You mistyped; it's "W**n**o", not "W**h**o". (Here's how that should be read and understood: `-W` is for "warning"; `no-` is negation; `error` turns warnings into errors; `date-time` is the kind of the warning.)

Comment: Sorry that was stupid of me.  This is where I'm at now: http://imgur.com/RD2IxeD

Comment: Awww, sorry! I forgot `sudo` sanitizes the environment. Try `CXXFLAGS="-Wno-error=date-time" sudo -E make` instead.

Comment: I think I might just have to try a different usb adapter http://imgur.com/GlgcvFw

Comment: If you have one, you might! If you don't, though, don't give up just yet. You can try `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=date-time" sudo -E make` (I somehow overlook the fact that the driver is in C, not C++. Sorry!); it might be useful to post the Makefile to [lpaste.net](http://lpaste.net) so I can ensure that it doesn't ignore said variables.

Comment: Current output: http://imgur.com/8wgcctR and what I think is the makefile: http://lpaste.net/161998  Thanks for sticking this out with me so far, haha.

Comment: Ah, so it ignored the `CFLAGS`. A bad sign. That was the last idea I had regarding environment variables. That's the Makefile, but all it does is run `make` on a Makefiles from other directories. Can you post `UTIL/Makefile`? Keep going, it's not over till we find out exactly *why* it won't work ;)

Comment: Scratch that; `UTIL/Makefile` actually works. it's `MODULE/Makefile` that fails. Can you post that one please?

Comment: I think this is it: http://lpaste.net/162003

Comment: Yeah, looks right. But this is getting increasingly unwieldy. Let's try a hack. (Ensure you either have original archive around, or make a backup—this might damage the driver's source and you'll have to remove it and start from scratch.) In the directory with the driver, first run `make clean` to remove any generated files, then `find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/-Werror//g'`. This will remove "turn warnings into errors" flag from all files, hopefully fixing the build. After that, try `sudo make`.

Comment: I tried highlighting lines where each screenshot begins/ends: http://imgur.com/a/cQAeQ

Comment: Argh! I'm out of ideas and out of steam. What I'm going to do right now is amend my answer to note that it didn't work and to sum up the discussion we just had. Maybe someone else will step up and provide more ideas. On the practical side of things, you might indeed start trying out different USB modems if you have them—but don't rush to buy any new stuff just yet, 4 hours isn't a lot of time for a community to react to a question. This is not over yet ;)